EM simulation of antenna in battery proximity using QUCS studio
Have you tried simulating the behaviour of a commercial IoT antenna with Lithium Ion batteries in proximity using QUCS studio?
I looked for tutorials but was not able to find anything useful. Can someone guide me?

that doesn't sound like something someone would do a tutorial on. Please explain exactly where you're stuck and what you need help with. Is assuming that you have basic versatility and can simulate the antenna without the battery? If not, you need to learn that first.

Yes simulating the antenna is fine, but I am unsure on how to make it interact with large metallic structures.

You probably don't need a tutorial. You just need to be able to simulate metal. The anodes of many lithium ion cylindrical cells is connected to the anode, so you'd just have to capacitavely couple that to your RF source. If the circuit ground is attached to anode then you could consider the outside of the battery at ground.
For pouch cells it's probably a different story.

okay I will try that. Thank you.

QUCS studio appears to be a circuit simulator. Determining the effect of nearby objects on radiation pattern, input impedance, etc. requires an EM simulator.

you can pair up QUCS studio with an open source EM simulator
